gradio how to hide a webcam interface
In Python 3.10 with gradio 4.44.1 on Windows 10, I struggle to hide a webcam "live" image with a button click. Currently, I am stuck with the following code:
import gradio as gr
import numpy as np

def flip(im):
    return np.flipud(im)

cam = gr.Image(sources=["webcam"], streaming=True)

with gr.Blocks(css="footer {visibility: hidden}") as demo:
    webcam = gr.Interface(
        flip,
        inputs=cam,
        outputs=None, # "image",
        live=True,
        clear_btn=None,
        show_progress='hidden'
    )
    hide_btn = gr.Button("Hide")

    def hide_cam(webcam):
        webcam.visible = False
        return webcam

    hide_btn.click(fn=hide_cam, inputs=webcam, outputs=webcam)
demo.launch()

After clicking the button the error  gradio.exceptions.InvalidComponentError: <class 'gradio.interface.Interface'> Component not a valid input component. shows up.
Can anyone please give me a hint, how to toggle the webcam visibility?

The problem is that you're passing the entire gr.Interface object (webcam) as an input or output to the hide_btn.click event, which is not valid. Instead you can pass the cam (gr.Image).
Also you need set visibility in the gradio dynamically so use gr.update() function.
Below is the code changed required to hide the cam. If you want to have toggle functionality you need to pass on the state in the function.
def hide_cam():
    return gr.update(visible=False)

hide_btn.click(fn=hide_cam, inputs=[], outputs=cam)


thanks, it works for hiding the cam component. I would have hoped that - on the contrary - using gr.update(visible=True) to show and reuse the hidden component again would work - which it does not. So, it's not a real hide() but more a destroy() : /

You can modify the the hide_cam functionality and pass a variable to keep track of visibility.
def toggle_cam_visibility(is_visible):
new_visibility = not is_visible
return gr.update(visible=new_visibility), new_visibility
visibility_state = gr.State(True)  # Initially the webcam is visible

hide_btn.click(fn=toggle_cam_visibility, inputs=[visibility_state], outputs=[cam, visibility_state])

